# Images are not shown in Chrome after changing list to grid

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm having a strange behaviour in Google Chrome browser. On my website I have a list / grid view. Changing between list and grid is done by Javascript and CSS. The only thing Javascript does is changing the css class of the list element.

So when I first load the page, all images are shown. But changing from list to grid, the images don't come back until I start scrolling or hover with the mouse over the image. See example below.
[image]

This only happens in Chrome (38.0.2125.104 m (64-bit))
No problems with IE, FireFox don't have this issue.

**EDIT**

The HTML, the class `grid` is changed to `list`.

```
<ul class="grid">
  <li><div>Div with product layout</div></li>
  <li><div>Div with product layout</div></li>
  <li><div>Div with product layout</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.grid > li {
  /*CSS HERE*/
}

ul.list > li {
  /*CSS HERE*/
}
```

Comment: I've never seen anything like that.. What if you use jQuery to simulate a mouseover on each li element after changing the class? Something like jQuery("ul.grid li").mouseover(). Or, again with jQuery, maybe try a very quick .hide() and then .show() of the entire ul?

Comment: @mike Willis, see answer of tmg below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar probleme with chrome rendering. Images are there but invisible till you hover or so. Try add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)`

Comment: By adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` in CSS to the `img{`, the images are stil not shown. But there is a difference. When I hover over one image, all images return at once and not only the one hovering.

Comment: the classes that you toggle with javascript, they changes the display property?

Comment: I updated my question with a little code example. I don't change the display property of the image. The CSS of the image is untouched by changing from list to grid.

Comment: can you try add -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) as well

Comment: Adding to the image class I suppose?

Comment: try on image and parent element of image

Comment: Great! Adding this only to the parent element fixed it!!